# How do I get the entity that represents the current user on a PHP template?

Tags: php, symfony

As it was answered on this question [How do I get the entity that represents the current user in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680917/how-do-i-get-the-entity-that-represents-the-current-user-in-symfony2) That shows you how to do it on a controller, but how do you do get the actual user entity on a php template without having to send it on a parameter to the template?

The far as I get was:

$app->getSession()->getUsername();

But that just gave a raw var with the user name, i want the *user entity*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FOSuserbundle Symfony2 accessing user data on any page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463650/fosuserbundle-symfony2-accessing-user-data-on-any-page)

Comment: Definitly not a duplicate of the link you added

Comment: @moonwave99 please read the question before putting a duplicate alert. This is for PHP templates, the other one is for TWIQ templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$app->getUser()` in the php template and `app.user` in the twig template.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html