# Symfony2 Get User Role in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, user-roles

I have one question,

How can i get User role in Symfony2 Twig.

I Had looking around but I couldn't find it.

Please help, or clue..

Thanks before.

Hendrawan

Comment: Do you use any bundle like FOSUserBundle ?

Comment: no I use symfony basic security

Comment: You can find the response here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463650/accessing-the-logged-in-user-in-a-template

Comment: You want to get the list of roles for 1 user ?
If you just want to test a role, see @IvanGabriele answer.
Do you use groups ?

Answer (score 31):

A simpler option could be to test the role since you have to define them in security.yml :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    Administrator
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    User
{% else %}
    Anonymous
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can write a Twig extension to accomplish this.

Create a twig extension and register it as a service.

1. in `services.yml` add

   ```
   services:
     cms.twig.cms_extension:
       class: Path\To\RolesTwigExtension.php
       tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
       arguments: ["@service_container"]
   ```
2. In `RolesTwigExtension.php`

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

   class RolesTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
       public function getFilters() {
           return array(
               new \Twig_SimpleFilter('getRoles', [$this, 'getRoles']),
           );
       }

       public function getName() {
           return 'roles_filter_twig_extension';
       }

       public function getRoles(UserInterface $user) {
           return $user->getRoles();
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your twig file:

   ```
   <ul>
       {% for key, value in app.user|getRoles %}
           <li>{{ value.name }}</li>
       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Silex:

```
{{ dump(app.user.roles) }}
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" }


{% if app.user is not null %}
  {% for role in app.user.roles if role != 'ROLE_ADMIN' %}
      {{ role }} //ROLE_USER
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the whole security token using `app.security.token`. Also `roles` is an attribute of token.

```
{{ dump(app.security.token.roles) }}
```

Comment: when I try it why the return value is like this : array (size=0)

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\Role)#1067 (3) { ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\Role":private]=> int(3) ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\Role":private]=> string(5) "admin" ["role":"AppBundle\Entity\Role":private]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" } }
This is my output

Comment: app.user.roles is now (3.x) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can scan your collection roles of User:

```html
{% for role in app.user.roles %}
{{ role }} <br> 
{% endfor %}
```